# What do you put in your standard etags --regex=.. calls?

Tags: emacs, tags, elisp

When I write some elisp code for a new Emacs "foo-mode" that contains a line like

```
(fset 'foo (if safe-mode 'fast-over-open-gently 'fast-over-open-everything-and-not-care)))
```

and later index the code with `etags foo-mode.el`, **etags** will not index the definition for **foo**. This is annoying since `(fset ...` is really used to define a function here, and an interactive one too.

The manual page for etags suggests that I can solve my problem with some **regex** parameter. Eventually, I managed to stumble upon the right parameter syntax and order with

```
etags --regex='{lisp}/(fset.*/' foo-mode.el
```

I am now considering developing and maintaining my own user-dependent list of regex-extensions for etags.
One can start and improve the above regex so that it matches less of the `(fset ..` line.

My question now: What other patterns do you usually want etags to index for lisp and elisp code? Share the good ideas! Most examples found on the web are in the etags man pages, and they do not include one lisp example :-(

PS:  on this machine `etags --version` says "etags (GNU Emacs 22.1)".

Comment: A related question (also with no answer):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290531/default-regular-expression-for-etags

Comment: This doesn't answer your `etags` question, but re: `fset` - it's better to use `defalias` for this purpose, as the latter handles certain symbol properties and updates `load-history` with the definition's location (I assume it also gets picked up by `etags`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found some examples at:
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/astaff/source/src-9.0/third/librep/Makefile.in

Here are the ones I'm using:

```
   --regex='/[ \t]+([ \t]*defun[ \t]+(?[ \t]*\([^ \t)]+\)/\1/'        
   --regex='/[ \t]+([ \t]*define[ \t]+(?[ \t]*\([^ \t)]+\)/\1/'       
   --regex='/[ \t]+([ \t]*defmacro[ \t]+(?[ \t]*\([^ \t)]+\)/\1/'     
   --regex='/[ \t]+([ \t]*defconst[ \t]+(?[ \t]*\([^ \t)]+\)/\1/'     
   --regex='/[ \t]+([ \t]*defvar[ \t]+(?[ \t]*\([^ \t)]+\)/\1/'
```

Alternatively, one that just captures "def" is pretty useful:

```
   --regex='/[ \t]+([ \t]*def[ \t]+(?[ \t]*\([^ \t)]+\)/\1/'
```