# Default regular expression for etags

Tags: emacs, elisp, etags

I'd like to create additional regular expressions for use with etags, but I'd like them to be based upon what's already there (in particular, I'd like to add [ \t]* to the current set of regular expressions that etags uses).  What are the default set of regular expressions that etags uses for .lisp files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

etags doesn't generally use regular expressions to implement the languages that are built-in.  Instead, it has custom parser code for each built-in language.

That said, it seems for Lisp to look for just a few forms, that could be handled by regular expressions:

- It looks for "(" in the first column
- It skips defvar
- It ignores a "cl-" or "CL-" appearing after the "("
- Then, "def" and "DEF" match
- It also checks for "(package::def" as a lead-in

I found this by reading lib-src/etags.c in the Emacs source tree.  Search for "Lisp_functions".